# SharePoint list Formula to calculate hours

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint list with two columns Start Time and end time. I want the Formula to calculate the time between the start time and end time in hours only.

If the end time is still pending (empty) value should be 0. The formula should calculate only working days and exclude weekends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using formula like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column2]),"0",TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h"))
```

**OR**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column2]),0,TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h"))
```

To exclude weekends, follow below posts:

1. [Exclude weekends](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268607/exclude-weekends)
2. [Calculating Dates Excluding Weekends](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194792/calculating-dates-excluding-weekends)
3. [Microsoft Lists - Date formula to exclude weekends](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289238/microsoft-lists-date-formula-to-exclude-weekends)
4. [Calculate days excluding weekends in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964332/calculate-days-excluding-weekends-in-sharepoint2010)

Comment: Or try using `hh` like: `=IF(ISBLANK([Column2]),0,TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"hh"))`